# youtube api could not be loaded revolution slider

Tags: jquery, wordpress, youtube, slider, fancybox

I use slider revolution plugin of WordPress and I load a YouTube in a popup when click play button using fancybox. The video is loaded by I receive this message before loading the video:

> "youtube api could not be loaded revolution slider"

```js
/* change revapi1 to whatever api number is being used for your slider */
var api = revapi1;
 
/* no need to edit below unless you want to change the default FancyBox settings */
api.on('revolution.slide.onloaded', function() {
 
    jQuery(this).find('.fancybox').each(function() {
 
        var $this = jQuery(this);
        if(!$this.is('a')) $this = $this.removeClass('fancybox').find('a');
 
        $this.addClass('fancybox').fancybox({
 
            /* begin FancyBox options */
            width: 960,            
            height: 540,
            autoSize: true,
            aspectRatio: true,
            fitToView: true,
            autoCenter: true,
            scrolling: 'no',
            type: 'iframe',
            onClosed: function() {api.revresume()}
 
        }).on('click', function() {api.revpause()});
 
    });
 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check the revolution slider api configuration settings, there is probably something amiss, you can test your API with Postman to be sure your api requests are working correctly.